# Angular2 route incorrectly reloads home page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Got a simple demo site with 2 pages (home and project). When I click from the homepage to the projectpage via the menubar everything works fine. But when I click a link from the homepage on a link to the projectpage, the projectpage is shown a second and than the homepage is reloaded. Anybody an idea what might be wrong? If I make a replace the anchor by a button, it works fine too! So I guess something wrong with **href=""**

**The routes:**

```
const routes: Routes =[
  { path: 'home',             component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'project',          component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
],
exports: [
],
```

})

**The nav-bar (works fine):**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/project']" class="nav-link">Project</a>
```

**The html (homepage - happens to be a component):**

```
<a href="" (click)="showProject()">project</a>
```

**The typescript (of the component):**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
  ...
}

public showProject() {
  this.router.navigate(['/project']);
}
```

Comment: Can you create a demo in stackblitz to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing, you need to remove the `href` attribute on html page:

The HTML anchor:

```
<a href="" (click)="showProject()">project</a>
```

Must use without `href` attribute.

```
<a (click)="showProject()">project</a>
```

Otherwise, the page will be reloaded entirely. Then, some suggestion on routing config. Change the route `constant` with:

```
const routes: Routes =[
  { path: 'home',             component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'project',          component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

In the component just modify the `showProject` method with:

```
public showProject() {
  this.router.navigate(['project']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try an empty [routerLink]

```
  <a [routerLink]="" (click)="showProject()">project</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that seems to work is replacing the href of the anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showProject()">
```